# Clear search session using keyup AJAX function

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can I add a timer function to clear out the search session created after user enters a search keyword. I can't seem to unset the search session. I've tried so many different ways to clear the search session and nothing works. I think the problem lies in this Ajax search function, its not clearing the results unless a user manually clears the search results.
So how can I add to this function a timer to "reset" and clear the search?
Thanks

```
if ($('#loaddata').attr("data-id") == '0') {
      $("#HelloWord").on("keyup", function() {
        
        var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        
        console.log(value);
        if (value != '') {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo $siteurl;?>search.php",
            data: {
              valuejj: value,
            },
            success: function(data2) {
              console.log(data2);
              

              if (data2 == 'dataPushed') {

                queryStringCategory2(pagevalue = 1);
              }
            }
          });


        }
        if (value == '') {
          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<?php echo $siteurl;?>SearchValueDestroyFromSession.php",
            data: {
              id: 1
            },
            success: function(data2) {
              if (data2 == 'done') {
                queryStringCategory2(pagevalue = 1);
              }
            }
          });


        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: What "session" are you talking about here?

Comment: Sorry I didn't explain too well, what I mean is that after the user enters text in search bar a session is crated on the PHP side, and for some reason that session is only destroyed when the same user clears the search input area.

Comment: _"and for some reason that session is only destroyed when the same user clears the search input area"_ - well when else did you expect it to happen? You are only calling the script to delete the session value, inside your keyup-handler, when the field value has become the empty string.

Comment: Is there a way to set a timer of sorts that clears the session value without having the user enable the keyup feature?

Comment: Sure, you could create something using `setTimeout`. Or you store the time you _make_ an entry, into the session as well - and then you simply discard it when _reading_ the session next time, if it is too old by then.